# Netstat output contains several connections with the same ip and port

Tags: tcp

Netstat output (`netstat -an`) contains several connections with the same foreign (client) ip and port, for example:

```
TCP    server_ip:49421     client_ip:4000     TIME_WAIT
TCP    server_ip:52772     client_ip:4000     TIME_WAIT
TCP    server_ip:56807     client_ip:4000     TIME_WAIT
TCP    server_ip:61969     client_ip:4000     TIME_WAIT
```

And this situation repeats after reduction of `TcpTimedWaitDelay` parameter in registry. 
Does it mean that server or client close sockets incorrectly or this is normal situation?

Comment: it looks like outgoing connections. means your server is accessing 4000 port of target machine.

Comment: @SunilBhoi yes, right. But does it mean that server closes sockets incorrectly or doesn't close sockets at all?.. Or is it OK?

Comment: it can be state just before closing connections. Generally, it closes with 5 min average time from the server. If this type of state is less in number then no need to worry.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: `TIME_WAIT` is a normal socket state to be expected, which appears when the local side of an established TCP connection asked to close the connection first. If the remote side had asked it first, then there would be no local `TIME_WAIT` but the remote side would keep a `TIME_WAIT` instead. There's nothing wrong with a great number of `TIME_WAIT` per se, that just means a great number of connections recently closed. It's up to you to decide if that's normal for your application and workflow or not.

The `TIME_WAIT`'s goal is to prevent immediate reuse of the same connection `localip:localport - remoteip:remoteport`, before the *Maximum Segment Lifetime*: wandering/duplicate packets from the previous connection on internet might arrive late and be considered part of the new connection, if they happen to have a matching sequence number. There are most probably additional things today that would prevent this to happen, that didn't exist in 1981 when TCP specifications were published.

reference: [RFC 793: Transmission Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) from 1981, see [3.5.  Closing a Connection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.5) Figure 13.

Also a quote from [3.3.  Sequence Numbers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.3):

> Knowing When to Keep Quiet
>
> To be sure that a TCP does not create a segment that carries a
> sequence number which may be duplicated by an old segment remaining in
> the network, the TCP must keep quiet for a maximum segment lifetime
> (MSL) before assigning any sequence numbers upon starting up or
> recovering from a crash in which memory of sequence numbers in use was
> lost.  For this specification the MSL is taken to be 2 minutes.  This
> is an engineering choice, and may be changed if experience indicates
> it is desirable to do so.  Note that if a TCP is reinitialized in some
> sense, yet retains its memory of sequence numbers in use, then it need
> not wait at all; it must only be sure to use sequence numbers larger
> than those recently used.

I understand that in this quote "TCP" means `localip:localport - remoteip:remoteport` and keeping quiet is enforced by `TIME_WAIT`.